# How to replace text in Python pandas with certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a column with websites that I want to replace all **"https://"** to **"www."** in my dataframe. For example, given the input:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://www.github.com
```

I run this:

```
data["columnname"]= data["columnname"].str.replace("https://", "www.", case = False)
```

The output is:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
www.www.github.com
```

However the output should be:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
www.github.com
```

Is there a better way to write the code to not double the **www.** when replacing the **https://**?

Comment: Your links are wrong. Also, don't add links. Instead paste everything as text.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I was using these links as an example as I didn't want to post the links in my actual dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a "double" replace and should first replace `www.` with an empty string to normalize the data and then replace `https://` with `www.`:

```
data["columnname"]= data["columnname"].str.replace("www.", "", case = False).str.replace("https://", "www.", case = False)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a further explanation on the "first replace `www.` with an empty string to normalize the data"?

Comment: @Nick you have to do the first one because you want to make the pattern with `https://` at the beginning common. You could also do `data["columnname"]= data["columnname"].str.replace("https://www.", "https://", case = False).str.replace("https://", "www.", case = False)` if that logically makes more sense, but the way I posted is the simplest syntax.